# refreshTokenWithAssertion Permission Denied

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am trying to use google-api-client in PHP for a project. 
I got a "permission denied" response while at this statement:

```
$client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
```

> Google_IO_Exception, Message:Failed to connect to 74.125.193.84: Permission denied
>   File: /home/www/blah.com/restful/libs/Google/IO/Curl.php
>   Line:81
>   /home/www/blah.com/restful/libs/Google/IO/Abstract.php(125): Google_IO_Curl->executeRequest(Object(Google_Http_Request))
>
> #1 /home/www/blah.com/restful/libs/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php(326): Google_IO_Abstract->makeRequest(Object(Google_Http_Request))
>
> #2 /home/www/blah.com/restful/libs/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php(306): Google_Auth_OAuth2->refreshTokenRequest(Array)
>
> #3 /home/www/blah.com/restful/v2/index.php(122): Google_Auth_OAuth2->refreshTokenWithAssertion()

I checked all my credentials and they look correct, what could be the problem?

Thanks,
John

code:

```
$client_id = '1234blahblahblah.apps.googleusercontent.com'; //Client ID
$service_account_name = '1234blahblah@developer.gserviceaccount.com'; //Email Address 
$key_file_location = 'blahblah-1234.p12'; //key.p12

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("test");
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);  
if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
}
$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);

$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_name,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'),
    $key
   );

print_r($cred);

$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

$client->setClientId($client_id);

if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion(); //<<<<<failed here.
} 
$_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken(); 
echo $_SESSION['service_token'];
}
```

Comment: this code resides in another restful .php file. I used chrome's restful client to test the .php, which in turn calls google api as above, is this correct way to test it?

Comment: It needs to be in sync with NTP.
Please review comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376791/fatal-error-uncaught-exception-google-auth-exception-with-message-error-refr#comment39574276_25376949

Comment: The method Google_Client#loadServiceAccountJson($jsonLocation, $scopes) can be used to create a Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials object. This method is not mentioned in the current documentation. It can directly handle the JSON file with all required data like the private key. [API documentation for authentication](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts)

Answer (score 1):

Hi John I´ve the same problem and finally this works for me:

Before the lines:

```
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion(); //<<<<<failed here.
}
```

I put a try catch and that returns me that I had a writtin permissions problem:

```
try {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

I could do 2 things:

1) Go to Google/src/Config.php and change line 94: 'directory' => sys_get_temp_dir() . '/Google_Client'and change the directory to save cache temp files

2) or like me, made a echo sys_get_temp_dir(); before the try catch and give a chmod 777 permission to that dir

This solution works for me, I hope also for you. Anyway made an try/catch waiting for the exception message

Comment: thanks Alberto. but i tried this method, but it did not work. from the trace, the error occurs at curl.php:  
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    if ($response === false) {
      throw new Google_IO_Exception(curl_error($curl));
    }

Comment: so curl.php is sending a post request to google api server and got a "permission denied" response, looks like credentials are not correct, but i checked, they are ok...

Comment: btw, echo sys_get_temp_dir() shows '\tmp', but i do not have this folder on the server. so i created one instead

Answer (score -2):

See the [service-account.php](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/service-account.php) sample in the [examples/](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/master/examples) directory of the Google APIs Client Library for PHP on Github.com:

```
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred); // set credentials there
}
```